# Return records that all match and all records where at least one doesn't match

Tags: sql, t-sql, inner-join, self-join

Given a table of exam results, where 1 == PASS and 0 == FAIL

```
ID    Name    Test   Result
--------------------
1     John    MATH   1
2     John    ENGL   1
3     Mary    MATH   1
4     Mary    PSYC   0
```

**EDIT**: assume that the name is unique.

I need to get all records for people who 
1) passed all tests
2) failed at least one test

So, the 1st query should return John and all his records, and the 2nd query should return Mary and all her records (including the ones with PASS).

I'm trying to do a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with itself and compare counts, but don't seem to get a working query.

```
SELECT * FROM Results R1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Results R2 on R1.ID=R2.ID and R2.Result=1
WHERE ??? count of rows from R1 is compared to count of non-null rows from R2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a "poster-child" exercise for the [`EXISTS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) clause:

At leasr one failed result:

```
select * from Results r
where exists (select * from Results rr where rr.Name=r.Name AND Result=0)
```

All passed:

```
select * from Results r
where not exists (select * from Results rr where rr.Name=r.Name AND Result=0)
```

See how these queries work on your data set [at `sqlfiddle.com`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2a4c4/4).

Comment: This will not work for the case of passed all tests since mary would return in both queries

Comment: @JustinPihony No, she would not be included in the "all passed" result, because of the `NOT` in front of `EXISTS`. See the link to [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2a4c4/5).

Comment: When you had the join on name you were right, but changing it to go off of ID is wrong. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d8b08/2

Comment: This is a good one too. The execution plan showed 49% vs 51% for this query vs the one posted by saul672.

Comment: @kateroh The two are different queries, though, because this one returns all records, whereas the other returns only the names. The query you pick depends entirely on what data set you're expected to get back.

Comment: @JustinPihony Thanks for noticing the issue! I'm sure in the real query there will be something better than a name to link two records, but as it currently stands, ID is an identifier of the record, not of the person.

Answer (score 2):

All passed

```
SELECT Name FROM Results R1
GROUP BY NAME
HAVING SUM(RESULT) = COUNT(RESULT)
```

Some failed

```
SELECT Name FROM Results R1
GROUP BY NAME
HAVING SUM(RESULT) < COUNT(RESULT)
```

Hope it helps

***Edit***

All passed

```
SELECT Name FROM Results R1
GROUP BY NAME
HAVING SUM(1-RESULT) = 0
```

Some failed

```
SELECT Name FROM Results R1
GROUP BY NAME
HAVING SUM(1-RESULT) > 0
```

(This might run faster)

Comment: As a note, you should probably not use name, but some unique identifier.

Comment: Two questions: Do I need to say this will only work when the result column has only 0 and 1 as stated?... Is it wrong to say I'm proud of my answer? (jk)

Comment: @JustinPihony is right, maybe the table should have a PersonID instead of the Name

Comment: I should probably post that the name is unique, so joining on the name is perfectly fine.

Comment: @saul672 the second query you posted, `SUM(1 - RESULT)` is much faster than what dasblinkenlight posted (40% vs 60%), but unlike his(her?) query yours doesn't return all records. Once I made it return all records, the tables flipped: 60% vs 40%.

Comment: If my query is returning less records is because it might be because it is grouping by name, as it is, dasblinkenlight's query is returning all the records of the persons that passed or failed (but maybe that's what you were looking for), if you change the `*` for `distinct Name` the results might be the same. Anyway, good luck with any method you select :P.

Comment: I just read the question again, i'm sorry you wanted ALL the records of the people that passed or failed, when I read it the first time I thought you were only interested in the Names. This can be archived by a left join with the results of my table but i think dasblinkenlight's solution will be faster.

Answer (score 1):

One way

```
  Select Name, 
     Case failCount When 0 then 'X' Else '' End PassedAll,
     Case failCount When 0 then '' Else 'X' End FailedOneOrMore
  From (Select name, 
        Sum(Case Result when 0 Then 1 Else 0 End) failCount
        From Results R
        Group By Name) Z
```

to get all the records, just join to this

```
   Select zz.Name, zz.PassedAll, zz.FailedOneOrMore,
      r.Test, r.Result 
   From (Select Name, 
             Case failCount When 0 then 'X' Else '' End PassedAll,
             Case failCount When 0 then '' Else 'X' End FailedOneOrMore
        From (Select name, 
              Sum(Case Result when 0 Then 1 Else 0 End) failCount
              From Results R
              Group By Name) Z) ZZ
       Left Join Results r On r.Name = zz.Name
```

Comment: this is a good one, but it returns only results that failed one or more

Answer (score 0):

This query uses a subquery to return all records (pass & fail) for people who have passed at least one of the Tests:

`select * from Results where Name in (select Name from Results where Result = '1' group by Name);`

Results exclude those who failed to pass any of the tests.